# TypeError: window.ResizeObserver is not a constructor

Tags: react-typescript, react-tsx

when i'm trying to run Chart.test.tsx with this code

```
import React from "react"
import { render } from "@testing-library/react"
import Chart from "./Chart"

describe("Render Chart", () => {
    it("Should Render Chart", () => {
        render(<Chart />)
        const chart = document.querySelector("#chart")
        expect(chart).toBeTruthy()
    })
})
```

it's give an error `TypeError: window.ResizeObserver is not a constructor`

how to make the error gone?